# How to normalize volume across regions in a Garageband track?

Tags: garageband

How can I normalize the volume across various regions in a track in Garageband?

Each region in my track has been recorded separately by a speaker with varying distances to the microphone, some are very loud in contrast to other quiet ones.

I've tried exporting with the "Auto Normalize" setting, but the loudest regions are still much louder than the quiet ones.